# nodejs app with forever in cronjob does not work after reboot

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, cron, forever

I created a cronjob with `sudo crontab -u USERNAME -e` and tried to start my node.js app after each reboot.

It had worked well at another server.

But this time, I installed the Node.js via `nvm`

Then tried to run the same cronjob lines, but every time after reboot it failed. I tried to figure out all the related folders and tried again to run as different lines. When I check with `forever list`, server shows that no process is running.

```
@reboot /home/USERNAME/.npm/forever start -c /home/USERNAME/.nvm/current/bin/node  /home/USERNAME/APPNAME/app
@reboot /home/USERNAME/.npm/forever start  /home/USERNAME/APPNAME/app
@reboot /usr/local/bin/forever start -c /home/USERNAME/.nvm/current/bin/node  /home/USERNAME/APPNAME/app
```

I think that the reason is somehow related with `nvm`. But I am not sure of that. I don't want to do anything unnecessary unless I am fully sure about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited July 26, 2015**

Though I have used the npm's forever module to deploy nodejs production apps, I really do not see the need to use it on linux based servers as there are so many system level alternatives available.

One of them is upstart. It will help you run your scripts as system level services. Amazon Web Services also use upstart in their Elastic Beanstalk nodejs tiers to keep nodejs apps running forever.

If you really just need to get down to it, here is a [link](http://kvz.io/blog/2009/12/15/run-nodejs-as-a-service-on-ubuntu-karmic/) to run your nodejs app as an upstart service.

However, it is not limited to deploying nodejs apps only and if you learn upstart, you will be able to do a lot of things with it. Here is a [link](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/) for that as well.

Comment: `which node
--> /home/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/v0.12.7/bin/node`

`which forever
--> /usr/local/bin/forever`

i checked both paths, and created 2 different lines for cronjob. but nothing happened. is there any other way without using @reboot command to do it?

`@reboot /usr/local/bin/forever start -c /home/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/v0.12.7/bin/node  /home/USERNAME/APPNAME/app.js
@reboot /usr/local/bin/forever start /home/USERNAME/APPNAME/app.js`

Comment: @Rephisto I have edited my answer. Please mark/upvote if it was helpful.

Comment: @Rephisto Have u found a solution for this? Me too cant make this work. I'm using something like : `@reboot /root/.nvm/versions/node/v7.1.0/bin/node /home/user/test.js`

Answer (score 0):

If your original approach was preferable (as it was in my case) you can fix your scheduled cron job by explicitly passing the path to node like this: (found in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/925849/177555))

```
@reboot /root/.nvm/versions/node/v7.1.0/bin/node /root/.nvm/versions/node/v7.1.0/bin/forever start /var/www/server.json
```

Apparently NVM works in magic by setting up some system paths which aren't setup at the moment the cron jobs run.

Comment: I have this same problem and still not working `@reboot /root/.nvm/versions/node/v7.1.0/bin/node /home/user/test.js`